# Difficulty in understanding JS callbacks on concatenation

Tags: javascript, callback

I am a student currently learning callbacks in javascript. I've consulted several learning aids and talked to several instructors but I cannot understand the following example's output:

```
let loopCB = function(val, num, cb) {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
   val = cb(val);           
  }
  return val
};

let result = loopCB("howdy", 6, function(s) {
  return s + "!";
});
console.log(result); // howdy!!!!!!
```

As I understand it, here the callback is being executed by the for loop in function `loopCB` `num` times -- if that's the case, how is it that `s` is unaffected by this loop?

My mind is unhappy that this is printing `howdy!!!!!!` and not printing `howdy!howdy!howdy!howdy!howdy!howdy!` -- how is it possible that the for loop is only affecting the concatenated `"!"` but not `s` itself?

Help is deeply appreciated, thank you for reading.

Comment: `cb(val)` (which is `function(s) { return s + "!"; }` ) just adds an exclamation mark to the end. Doesn't append the string to itself. Moreover, strings are immutable so `s + "!"` doesn't even alter `s` because it cannot.

Comment: Ah, thanks. When `s` was a number the loop and operator were able to effect the reassigned product and that was thoroughly confusing me.

Thanks for the bit about immutability - I had a hunch that was the case however my instructors insisted immutability was immaterial to this problem.

Your answer is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, immutability *is immaterial*. I only mentioned it because you said you expected `s` to change. But there is nothing that changes `s`. Nor can `s` change. So, the expectation was wrong.

Comment: *Yes, immutability is immaterial*   --  

Oh dear, It seems I don't understand this after all. I will ponder more.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is running the function that was passed in with name `cb`. The function only does one thing, it returns the value with an exclamation mark on the end.

```
const ourFunction = function(s) {
  return s + "!";
}
ourFunction("yellow") // "yellow!"
```

The value `val` starts as "howdy", and then it is put through the function many times.

To give a brief example, here's what it would look like if we broke the for loop out:

```
let val = "howdy";
val = cb(val); // "howdy!" // one exclamation was added.
val = cb(val); // "howdy!!" // another exclamation was added.
```

When the looping is done, the final output `"howdy!!!!!!"` is returned.

Note that the function does not mutate the entered values.
If we slightly alter your example, this is much easier to demonstrate:

```
let loopCB = function(val, num, cb) {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
   val = cb(val);           
  }
  return val
};

// new declarations
const ourString = "howdy";
const ourFunction = function(s) {
  return s + "!";
};

let result = loopCB(ourString, 6, ourFunction); // new variables passed in here
console.log(result); // "howdy!!!!!!"
console.log(ourString); // "howdy"
```

`ourString` is never changed. The function takes it, and then returns a *new* string that starts with `ourString` and has an exclamation mark on the end.

In the for loop, `val` is constantly mutated, but `val` is a *copy* of `ourString`, not a reference to the same variable.

Comment: checking my understanding here --  so... *because* `s` is the parameter in the CB, it is essentially unaffected by the for loop / unaffected by multiple calls in your example?  It's just being passed through and only the `"!"` is being acted upon?     

My breakdown in understanding here seems to be why something like: 

`const ourFunction = function(s) {
  return s * 10;
}
ourFunction(9) // 90`
`let val = 10;
val = cb(val); // 100
val = cb(val); // 1000`

Seems to effect the whole return inside `ourFunction`

Comment: @geberaDays it only changes `val`. Same as the code in the question - only `val` is changed then. But it's overwritten each time.

Answer (score 0):

Added few consoles to better understand the code flow. I hope this will make things clear:

```js
let loopCB = function(val, num, cb) {
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
 console.log("val before fun call=", val)
 val = cb(val);  
 console.log("val after fun call=", val)         
}
return val
};

let addExclamation = function(s) {
console.log("input=",s)
return s + "!";
}
let result = loopCB("howdy", 6, addExclamation);
console.log(result);
```

```
i=0
val before fun call=howdy
input=howdy
val after fun call=howdy!

i=1
val before fun call=howdy!
input=howdy!
val after fun call=howdy!!

i=3
val before fun call=howdy!!
input=howdy!!
val after fun call=howdy!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing so you are not chaining **howdy** in any way.

Everytime you do this

```js
val = cb(val);
```

you are overwriting **val** with **howdy!"** **howdy!!"** **howdy!!!..."**

I guess, to get what you expect you should change this:

```js
val = cb(val);
```

to

```js
val += cb(val);
```

Now you have

```
howdyhowdy!howdyhowdy!!howdyhowdy!howdyhowdy!!!howdyhowdy!...
```

Comment: Oh *snap* thank you so much, this really hit it home in my brain for me